# Alternative to Farm Service Agency (FSA) CLU dataset?

Tags: data, land-use

Is there an alternative dataset that can I find that is similar to the Farm Service Agency (FSA) [Common Land Unit (CLU)](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/FSA/apfoapp?area=home&subject=prod&topic=clu) ?

Comment: What are you interested in checking?

Comment: FSA use land class code but doesn't really tell you what their land use is just a numbers. All I want the land use for a particular area near south of  Albuquerque. I am looking at from the years from 2004 to now that may be helpful for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLU isn't avaialble to the public. For most part it's kept under lock and key. People can get into legal trouble if they allow, knowing or not, the CLU get out into the public domian. At least, that is what we are told. :)

There are individuals and groups outside of USDA who have access to the data. But they had to sign agreements inorder to gain acccess to the data.

It's considered Personal Idenifiable Information. That's is a arugement for another time.

Also, more to your question. I wouldn't use it for landcover or use. It has it's issues, just like any other dataset. Like boundaries not matching the imagery for example. One CLU field could represent multiple landcover or uses. And probably more imporpant, it's doens't cover 100% of the land. Only those portions which are or have been in one type of USDA program.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two products available from the [NRCS Geospatial Data Gateway](http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/GDGOrder.aspx):

[2011 National Land Cover Data Set (NLCD)](http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd2011.php)

> National Land Cover Database 2011 (NLCD 2011) is the most recent
>   national land cover product created by the Multi-Resolution Land
>   Characteristics (MRLC) Consortium. NLCD 2011 provides - for the first
>   time - the capability to assess wall-to-wall, spatially explicit,
>   national land cover changes and trends across the United States from
>   2001 to 2011. As with two previous NLCD land cover products NLCD 2011
>   keeps the same 16-class land cover classification scheme that has been
>   applied consistently across the United States at a spatial resolution
>   of 30 meters. NLCD 2011 is based primarily on a decision-tree
>   classification of circa 2011 Landsat satellite data.

[USDA-NASS Cropland Data Layer](http://www.nass.usda.gov/research/Cropland/SARS1a.htm)

> The USDA-NASS Cropland Data Layer is a raster, geo-referenced,
>   categorized land cover data layer produced using satellite imagery
>   from the Thematic Mapper (TM) instrument on Landsat 5, Landsat7, or
>   the Advanced Wide Field Sensor (AWiFS) on RESOURCESAT-1. The imagery
>   was collected between the dates of 03/01/1997 and now. The approximate
>   scale is 1:100,000 with a ground resolution of 30 meters by 30 meters
>   for the TM data, 56 meters by 56 meters for the AWiFS data. The data
>   layer is aggregated to a possible 85 standardized categories for
>   display purposes, with the emphasis being agricultural land cover.
>   Most data layers average about 10 to 20 categories out of the 85
>   possible categories.

Also, cropland data is available from [CropScape](http://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/)

Comment: Thank you, Aaron. Another way you can go to http://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/

Comment: That is a great resource I was unaware of, thank you @PROBERT.  I will include it in the answer for future readers.

Comment: The first 5 years from 2013 to 2008, you can download for any specific area (AOI) or all of the states; however, for the pre- 2007 years, you can check on the enable on 2007 or previous  and it will show you which state is available or not or if want  you can download that has available states. (That takes a while to download to your computer.